# openssl crl "Error getting CRL issuer certificate" reasons

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, openssl, crl, pem

CRL file A - http://pastebin.com/ZXGk9p0X
CA file B in directory "dir1" http://pastebin.com/05PKGCjH

openssl crl -in A -CApath dir1

gives the error 
Error getting CRL issuer certificate

I had earlier posted a similar question - but there my cert was actually wrong.

Here I think it's correct

openssl x509 -in dir1\B

subject= /C=IN/O=India PKI/CN=CCA India 2011

openssl crl -in A -issuer

issuer=/C=IN/O=India PKI/CN=CCA India 2011

How do I troubleshoot this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you did not specify the filename for the certificate my guess is that you just placed it into the directory given by `-CApath` without taking care of the special file name as needed. From the [documentation of x509](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.1/apps/x509.html):

> -subject_hash
>        outputs the "hash" of the certificate subject name. This is used in OpenSSL
>        to form an index to allow certificates in a directory to be looked up by 
>        subject name.

Also the documentation of `-CApath` for [openssl crl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.1/apps/crl.html) states:

> -CApath dir
>   verify the signature on a CRL by looking up the issuing certificate in dir. This directory must be a standard certificate directory: that is a **hash of each subject name (using x509 -hash) should be linked to each certificate**.

If you use the hash `c7f51c60` returned by `openssl x509 -subject_hash` as the base for the filename, i.e. put the certificate into `dir1/c7f51c60.0` then it works. If you don't want to fiddle with these special filename just put all the certificate into a single file and use `-CAfile` instead.